# Arranging the checkbox items belonging to same category into one section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

With my e-commerce requirements, I have a filter that consists of multiple checkboxes. The user selects one or multiple checkboxes to filter the list of items in a table.

The checkboxes arrangement looks something like this (sample):

```
Mathematics
  maths checkbox1
  maths checkbox2
  maths checkbox3

Physics
  phy checkbox1
  phy checkbox2
  phy checkbox3
```

As any of the filters(checkboxes) are selected, the filters have to be displayed in a component, like this:

[image]

With some workaround, I was able to implement a single array containing the selected filter but not sure how to handle this particular way of grouping filters belonging to a same category.

Tried so far:

```
 initialstate = {
       filters: [
            {
                title: '',
                options: [
                    {
                        name: '',
                        key: '',
                        label: '',
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
       selected: []
    }
```

const setFilters = (value) => {

```
setFilterOptions((state) => {

    const selectedFilters = state.selected.find(
        (obj) => obj === value
    );

    const selected = selectedFilters
        ? state.selected.filter(
            (obj) => obj !== value
        )
        : [...state.selected, value];


    return {
        selected,
        filters: [
            ...state.filters.map((filter) => {
                return {
                    ...filter,
                    options: filter.options.map((ele) => {
                        return {
                            ...ele,
                            checked: selected.includes(ele.label)
                        };
                    })
                };
            })
        ]
    };
});
```

};

The algo that I could think of:

1. function `setFilters(value)` takes the `label` of the filter selected.
2. component state:

const [filterOptions, setFilterOptions] = useState(initialState);

3. inside this function, loop over the `state.selected` array of objects and check to which category the `value` belongs.
4. if the `value` does not exist for that category, add it an array. If it already exists (for the same category), then push it to the respective array.
5. map over the final array to render the names of the filters (as in picture).

I am a bit confused about how to implement this logic actually.

Need a bit help to implement this in the best possible way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will your filters array always contain ALL filters that you will need to search for? I'm curious how you figure out which options belong to which filter categories.

Comment: See it goes like. The filter options are fixed for each category. As the user keeps on selecting the filter options, the selected options need to be shown. But the filters selected from the same category need to be listed together, if from another category, then it should be treated as a separate filter. Just as given in the sample image below. Reference link for filteration: https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/p/pl?N=101295859%201065785072%20601321880%201065789089

Comment: So, I am unable to figure out how to match that which option belongs to which category?

Comment: Do you have to try and figure out which option belongs to which Category? I'm assuming you have some sort of on click listener where you pass in the value the clicked option. Why not pass in the category title as a second parameter to that function? Then you will know exactly which category the option clicked on belongs to.

Comment: I was trying something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-e2zd3. But does not seems to work or I am unable to implement logic properly

Comment: Interesting. The login should basically be the same. You'd just need to update your view on how it renders the selected values. There are some slight modifications needing to be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220165/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-chris).