# How to set the state when radio button is by default checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, web-frontend

You see here, the first radio button `defaultChecked={index === 0}` is by default checked. I am storing the mapped `variant` object when it's changed.`onChange`. how do I store the value of `variant` when user doesn't change anything and just press add item?

I can't set the state inside `.map` it causes render issues.

```
const [variantOption, setVariantOption] = useState({});
const [variant, setVariant] = useState([]);
props.selectedCustomItem.variants.map((variant, index) => {
{variant.options.map((option, index) => {
<input
type="radio"
name="variant-select"
id="variant-select"
defaultChecked={index === 0}
value={option.price}
onChange={(e) => {
setVariantOption(option);
setVariant(variant);
}}
/>}
<button
  onClick={() => {
    props.addFoodItems(variant, variantOption);
  }}
>add item</button>
```

Comment: If you are using checkbox and the first is by default selected, then you can initialise your state with the first value present in the state like `useState(props.selectedCustomItem.variants[0])`

Comment: I could do that but there's also another ```.map``` in variants, it's called ```variant.options.map(option, index)``` so If I have to select option I'll have to ```useState(props.selectedCustomItem.variants[0].options[0]```

Comment: ok, as per your question it seems you are mapping over `props.selectedCustomItem.variants` and not over `options` which is present inside the `variants`. Can you please update the question accordingly? It will help in providing better solution.

Comment: @SumitSurana I made mistack , sorry. Take a look at the code now. There's only one input element but it's inside 2 ```.map``` function.

Comment: I have updated the suggestion accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using checkbox and the first is by default selected, then you can initialise your state with the first value present in the state like useState(props.selectedCustomItem.variants[0])

```
const [variantOption, setVariantOption] = useState();
const [variant, setVariant] = useState(props.selectedCustomItem.variants[0]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (variantOption == null && variant && variant.length > 0) {
    setVariantOption(variant.options[0]);
  }
}, [variantOptions, variant]);

props.selectedCustomItem.variants.map((variant, index) => {
{variant.options.map((option, index) => {
<input
type="radio"
name="variant-select"
id="variant-select"
defaultChecked={index === 0}
value={option.price}
onChange={(e) => {
setVariantOption(option);
setVariant(variant);
}}
/>}
<button
  onClick={() => {
    props.addFoodItems(variant, variantOption);
  }}
>add item</button>
```

Also, I assume that `props.selectedCustomItem.variants` is not null or undefined.

Comment: yes, it's not. If in any case it'll be null or undefined I will take actions according to that when I'm passing it inside of onClick ```props.addFoodItems(variantOptiont);```

Comment: You answer works for me now. But just for fun, imagine the situation in future where we have length of variants more than 1., and also have multiple options for each variants. what would be appropriate solution for that? Thanks again

Comment: The approach would be quite different, here it works because you are using a radio button which means at any given time you have one option only. For checkbox logic, the approach would be quite different. There are many examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456350/handling-checkboxes-with-nested-array-of-objects and https://dev.to/jadzeino/writing-a-nested-checkbox-component-with-react-react-admin-1hb5